# Is methyl cellulose edible?

Tags: culinary-uses, gelling-agents

I blend methyl cellulose for cosmetic products (I use the fine powder). Is methyl cellulose edible?  I want to make an edible gel without sugar; just stevia and fruit flavours.

Comment: There are several related questions: [methylcellulose for gel noodles](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13142/what-type-of-methylcellulose-would-be-appropriate-for-gel-noodles), [vegetarian marshmallows](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11745/how-can-i-make-vegetarian-marshmallows), and others - just search for methyl cellulose or methocel!

Answer (score 2):

Methylcellulose is commonly used in molecular gastronomy to raise the freezing temperture of solids and liquids. Think piping-hot ice cream.

For the gel, you could use agarose (commonly agar) to create a jelly.

The other obvious choice for the gel would be gelatin. Buy plain gelatin at the store and have at it with the directions.

You can create a foam using either the gelatin or the agar and an N2O whipper. This is also called an espuma.

The third, more fun choice would be to get thee to an asian food store and buy and flavor some tapioca pearls.

Comment: hey that does sound fun. Thanks technowizard12. Must check nutritional info on tapioca. I love sago pudding asian style. I am trying to imagine piping hot icecream? Will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

[This (e)Book](http://blog.khymos.org/wp-content/2009/02/hydrocolloid-recipe-collection-v3.0.pdf) has a number of recipes involving meythlcellulose (a.k.a. methyocel), including:

- noodles (cream cheese, olive oil, parsley)
- foams (generic, carrot)
- marshmallows
- puddings
- hot ice cream (vanilla, Bailey's)
- burgers
- films (mozzarella, etc)
- and more

Comment: wonderful, thank you Ray, my only experience to date is using it to make an aloe vera gel. Great ebook cool.