# How much of methylcellulose is safe?

Tags: food-safety

Not a duplicate of [this](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13406/is-methyl-cellulose-edible) question, as I know that it's used for cooking, I just don't know how much of it is safe.

I heard that methylcellulose is used as a laxative (it is not digestible, just like regular cellulose), and I heard it has other side effects that caused the food industry to limit its use. I'm concerned that too much of it may cause diarrhea. I believe some small amount should still be safe, otherwise it wouldn't be used at all. The question is: how much? And does safety depend on methylcellulose/total food mass proportion, or does it depend on the amount of methylcellulose alone? Any personal experiences?

Comment: In my opinion is totally safe chemically. But fibers can be more or less tolerated by different individual.  What I want to say is that you could replace all cellulose intake by methilcell, nothing should change. I comment because this my chemical reasoning. I want to point out the similarity. If one is sensitive to fibers, no matter if cellulose or a simple derivative as methylcellulose. The latter is used as anti constipation remedy but because is easy to assume. Cellulose should do the same once inside.

Comment: @Alchimista Googled some more. Apparently methylcellulose is used both in constipation AND diarrhea. Interesting. Then I assume that in a way it can be used as alternative to fiber supplements, and in terms of overdose it's no more dangerous than eating too much fiber. There's too much of something for anything though. Oh well, I guess it's not much of a concern. Thank you.

Comment: Yes sure there is too much of everything (almost :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no safe number determined.

The position of the FDA is

> There is no evidence in the available information on methyl cellulose that demonstrates, or suggests reasonable grounds to suspect, a hazard to the public when it is used at levels that are now current and in the manner now practiced. However, it is not possible to determine, without additional data, whether a significant increase in consumption would constitute a dietary hazard.

(from [SCOGS](http://wayback.archive-it.org/7993/20171031063406/https://www.fda.gov/Food/IngredientsPackagingLabeling/GRAS/SCOGS/ucm260473.htm))

So, all you can do is to follow recipes and hope that they constitute "levels that are now current and in the manner practiced".